# What's the main difference between the two logging configuration

Tags: python, logging

I'm working on logging configuration to make it be a standard log library of kinds of python projects.

But something weird happened: in previous case with "configure2", the main file "test1" always print twice. So if I have imported the other library with same logger library , it will print the same number times.

And in case "configure1", everything seems going well. So could you guys tell me why this would happen and what happened in logging function?

logger.py:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import logstash

def configure1():
    host = '10.211.55.12'
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,)
    # fileConfig(log_file_path)

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.addHandler(logstash.TCPLogstashHandler(host, 514, version=1))
    return logger


def configure2():
    host = '10.211.55.12'

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fh = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    logger.addHandler(logstash.TCPLogstashHandler(host, 514, version=1))
    return logger
```

test1.py:

```
import logger
import test2
logger = logger.configure1()
#logger = logger.configure2()
logger.info('hello from test1')
```

test2.py:

```
import logger
logger = logger.configure1()
#logger = logger.configure2()
logger.info('hello from test2')
```

configure1 result:

```
INFO:logger:hello from test2
INFO:logger:hello from test1
```

configure2 result:

```
hello from test2
hello from test1
hello from test1
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Logging Hierarchy**

Python loggers are arranged in a *hierarchy*, with the root logger on top being represented in an empty string, and names being descendants. This works similar to a file hierarchy, with `'a.x'` and `'a.y'` being descendants of `'a'`, and `'a'` and `'b'` being descendants of the root logger.

Each logger handles an incoming log message and then passes it on to its parent. Each logger that does not have a loglevel set will check its parents until it finds one with the loglevel set. (This is the difference between `logger.level` and `logger.getEffectiveLevel()`)

One important thing to remember is that `basicConfig` configures the *root* logger, while `logger.addHandler` and `logger.setLevel` operate on the logger you requested (typically the module's logger). Also `basicConfig` can only be called once, subsequent calls to it will be ignored.

In your case there are 2 loggers:

```
          '' (root)
         /  
        /    
'logger' (__name__ in logger.py, this is NOT 'test1' or 'test2'!)
```

**logger.py**

Let's take out `logstash` as we can't see the results and let's put in print statement to help understand what's going on:

```py
import logging

def configure1():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    print('root   =', logging.getLogger('').handlers)
    print('logger =', logging.getLogger('logger').handlers)
    return logger

def configure2():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fh = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    print('root   =', logging.getLogger('').handlers)
    print('logger =', logging.getLogger('logger').handlers)
    return logger
```

**configure1()**

Your call to `basicConfig()` initializes the root logger, which gets a `StreamHandler <stderr>` attached to it, which results in you being able to view both log messages.

```
root   = [<StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>]
logger = []
root   = [<StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>]
logger = []
INFO:logger:hello from test2
INFO:logger:hello from test1
```

**configure2()**

`basicConfig()` is **not** called, so the root logger does **not** have any handlers here. However, each call to `configure2()` **adds** a StreamHandler to the 'logger' logger.

```
root   = []
logger = [<StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>]
root   = []
logger = [<StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>, <StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>]
hello from test2
hello from test1
hello from test1
```

**So what to do?**

What you actually want is a logger whose name corresponds to the module emitting the log message. So I recommend placing `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` at top-level in each productive module and using that to log.

Configure your logging by having a separate module which either configures the root logger (for applications) or the package logger (`logging.getLogger('yourpackagename')`, for libraries and packages) and just running this once at the start of your program.